# Excel vba: restrict edit area in excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I want to restrict the users to edit range in Ms Excel sheet.

```
Scenario:

  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | ... IV
-------------------------------------------
1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------
2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------
3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------
4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------------------------
...
65536
```

In the above spreadsheet  user should have access to edit the range `Column A` to `Column H`. `Column I to IV` users should not allow to edit any text or anything. No restriction on number of rows.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could _at least_ comment on the answers offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this programatically, try this in a module (and adapt it to suit your needs):

```
Sub ProtectAToH()
Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Columns("A:H").Locked = False
  ws.Protect Contents:=True, Password:="myPassword"
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In three steps

1) Select the whole sheet. Format->Lock Cells->Remove locking for all cells. (All cells are initially "locked" by default)

2) Select your desired locking columns. Format->Lock Cells->Apply Locking  (This is declarative, you are not locking nothing, just declaring what you will lock in the next step)

3) Format-> Protect Worksheet.  (This trigger the real protection)

You are done.

HTH

Comment: Since all cells are, indeed,  initially locked, point 1 and 2 should be replaced by a single step = "SELECT columns to unlock, Format->Lock Cells->Remove locking"

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives to sasfrog and belisarius proposals (just to enrich your options):

a) you may also just HIDE columns K:IV, and protect the worksheet to prevent unhiding
b) Using the Tools, Protection, "Allow users to edit ranges" option, define range $a:$h as editable without password for users belonging to Everyone group, then protect your sheet. I like that one.

Don't forget that any solution involving Excel built in protection will prevent your users from inserting/deleting rows.

c) Using VBA (would not prevent deleting/inserting rows):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("$h:$iv")) Is Nothing) Then
    Target.Value = ""  'or something else'
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = "$A:$H"
```

will restrict what cells the user can select.

Answer (score 0):

iDevlop's option c) should be modified to prevent an infinite loop:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:G25")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then                  'Prevent Error on Row Insert or Delete
            If Not Target.Value = "" Then Target.Value = "" 'Prevent infinite loop
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will still allow a user to make a multi-cell copy paste into your specified Intersect range. Havent figured that one out.